# How do Windows task scheduler recognise if the task fails

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I have configured a application in Windows task scheduler to run for every 5 mints.

Expected true , but the application returns false and I expect the windows task scheduler to recognise it & restart. But it's not happening so far. Scheduler keeps running.

Note : I have enabled the option "to restart if the task fails for every" as well in scheduler.

Pls let me know where do I make mistake in understanding. Thanks.

Comment: When you say "returns false" what does that mean exactly? Does it output a message that says "false", or is it a program the has a non-zero exit code? Something else? What kind of task is it?

Comment: I am running a python code & to establish socket connection. I assume like if the connection is not available & failed for quite few seconds,  then I expect scheduler to restart the application.

Comment: Does your python code exit with an error code when it gets an error from the connection attempt? If not, Windows may not see the error since your code experienced the error, but then exited successfully.

Comment: No it will not produce any code but simply will be in loop saying server not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of hours on trial & error, found that system event would solve the above issue. scheduler doesn't track the error code of ongoing application, rather it will only the status  whether its running or not.

Comment: The scheduler has no way of knowing whether your application, while it's running, experiences an error internally and then handles the error itself and continues to run. As far as Windows is concerned, your application is continuing to run successfully.